# How to solve the ValueError importing torch in python

Tags: python, pytorch, torch

After installing pytorch package, I have tried to import pytorch with

```
import torch
```

but got the error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
  File "c:\users\user\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\torch\__init__.py", line 190, in <module>
    from torch._C import *
ValueError: module functions cannot set METH_CLASS or METH_STATIC
```

from searching, I have read that this could be about numpy. So I have tried uninstalling and installing with those

```
pip uninstall numpy
pip install numpy -I
pip install numpy -U
```

It didn't work.

I would be happy to hear from you if you have any idea why such an error occurs and how to correct it?

in case needed: Python version 3.8.6 ,
torch version 1.7.0 ,
numpy version 1.19.4

Comment: Can you try going back to an older version of numpy, say, `1.16.5`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The latest version of numpy for the moment is 1.19.4

I have uninstalled numpy and installed 1.19.3 version. After a complete restart of the system. The error does not show anymore. Thanks.